# Convert URL Request from Android to IOS

Tags: android, swift, request, alamofire

I need to make a request to get a token.

If my data isn't correct, i get right answer with "Wrong data"

But if my data is correct, I get an answer:

> responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength).

But it works on Android version.

Request Code for Android:

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/v1/authorization/login")
    fun login(
        @Field("username") username: String,
        @Field("password") password: String,
        @Field("code") code: String
    ): Single<Response<Void>>
```

API:

```
{
    "name": "Get token",
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "header": [],
        "url": {
            "raw": "http://192.168.9.41/api/v1/authorization/login?username=%2B79992402979&password=Qwerty%244&code=4242",
            "protocol": "http",
            "host": [
                "192",
                "168",
                "9",
                "41"
            ],
            "path": [
                "api",
                "v1",
                "authorization",
                "login"
            ],
            "query": [
                {
                    "key": "username",
                    "value": "%2B79992402979"
                },
                {
                    "key": "password",
                    "value": "Qwerty%244"
                },
                {
                    "key": "code",
                    "value": "4242"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "response": []
}
```

My Swift code:

```
func confirmLoginWithCode(username: String, password: String, code: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
        "code": code
    ]
    let url = "\(self.baseUrl)/api/v1/authorization/login"
    let authRequest = AF.request(url,
                                 method: .post,
                                 parameters: parameters,
                                 encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString))
    authRequest.responseString { (response) in
        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(let value):
            let responseArr = value.components(separatedBy: "\u{0022}")
            print(responseArr, "success")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("\(error) check error")
        }
        completion()
    }
}
```

Comment: The API responding empty data, is that normal?

Comment: @Larme Hello, my dear friend. I'm so glad to see message from u)))
You help me again.
Token must be in the header, not in the response

Comment: Token must be in response header? Not in body response?

Comment: If your response doesn't include data its HTTP code should be 204 (No-Content) or 205 maybe. I'm not an expert on that part.. If you have control on the server, ty to apply. Else, you can parse the error, if that's the empty response, ignore it, and read the value from `response.response`, and get the headers from there with `value(forHTTPHeaderField:)`.

Comment: @Larme Yep, does it look weird?
I try to know now may i read response header with reponseString?

Comment: @Larme Ok, thank u so much. I'll try it and write about success here. 
God bless u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I realize that my question is pretty useless for the site, but here is my solution:
As it turned out, I just had to look in Header

```
func confirmLoginWithCode(username: String, password: String, code: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
            let parameters: Parameters = [
                "username": username,
                "password": password,
                "code": code
            ]
            let url = "\(self.baseUrl)/api/v1/authorization/login"
            let authRequest = AF.request(url,
                                         method: .post,
                                         parameters: parameters,
                                         encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString))
            authRequest.responseString { (response) in
                switch(response.result) {
                case .success(let value):
                    let responseArr = value.components(separatedBy: "\u{0022}")
                    if responseArr[31] == "Wrong verification code!" {
                        self.confirmLoginStatus = .incorrectCode
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    if let receivedHeaders = response.response?.headers.value(for: "Authorization") {
                        let token = receivedHeaders.replacingOccurrences(of: "Bearer ", with: "")
                        self.userSettings.token = token
                        self.confirmLoginStatus = .success
                    } else {
                        self.confirmLoginStatus = .connectionError
                    }
                    self.errorStatus = error.errorDescription ?? "some error"
                }
                completion()
            }
        }
```